# How to show/hide an item by hover and also by random delay

Tags: jquery, events

I have an item1 which shows/hides an item2 by mouse hover:

```
$(function() {
    $("#item1").hover(function() {
        $("#item2").show();
    }, function() {
        $("#item2").hide();
    });
});
```

I would like to make item2 also shown and hidden by random time delay in paralell with hover-in/hover-out on item1. How can I do that?

Comment: how do you want to hover something that is hidden?

Comment: If `display` is `none` then you can't hover!

Comment: You need to elaborate on your question

Comment: Right, thanks, I have rewritten it.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval( function() {
        $("#item2").toggle('slow');
    }, 2000);
    $(function() {
        $("#item1").hover(function() {
            $("#item2").show();
        }, function() {
            $("#item2").hide();
        });
    });
});
```

In action-> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epeS4/) - [epeS4](http://jsfiddle.net/epeS4/)

Comment: Not really sure what OP wanted, but I would expect the toggle loop stops on hover..

Comment: He wants the toggle `in parallel`. Yeah, have to wait for the OP.

Comment: Yes, stop on hover is a good idea. I didn't realize it yet, but Michal's expectation is right. Thank you for good questions, they help me to clarify my request.

Answer (score 1):

Increment and multiply the random number according to your needs:

```
$(function() {

    var blocked = false;

    function divToggle() {
        if (!blocked) {
            $("#item2").toggle();
        }
        setTimeout(divToggle, Math.random() * 2000);
    };

    divToggle();

    $("#item1").hover(function() {
        blocked = true;
        $("#item2").show();
    }, function() {
        blocked = false;
        $("#item2").hide();
    });

});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZFew/2)